# Python Web scraping BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, beautifulsoup

My code is stuck in infinite loop although it is not not infinite it just give me the same list 50 or more times. My code was working fine yesterday it was only printiing it once but all of a sudden now same code is stuck in loop.
Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



url = 'https://business.narimn.org/list/searchalpha/a'
response = requests.get(url, timeout=50)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

cls = soup.find_all('div', class_='gz-list-card-wrapper')
print(len(cls))
modeling_company = []
for cl in cls:
  try:
    a_tag = cl.find('a')
    if a_tag:
      link = a_tag['href']
      response = requests.get(link, timeout=50)
      soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
      company_name = soup.find('h1', class_='gz-pagetitle').get_text()
      address = soup.find('li', class_='list-group-item gz-card-address')
      street_ad = address.find('span', class_='gz-street-address').get_text() if address else ''
      city_ad = address.find('span', class_='gz-address-city').get_text() if address else ''
      state_ad = address.find('span', itemprop='addressRegion').get_text() if address else ''
      zip_code = address.find('span', itemprop='postalCode').get_text() if address else ''
      p_n = soup.find('li', class_='list-group-item gz-card-phone')
      phone = p_n.find('span', itemprop='telephone').get_text() if p_n else ''
      modeling_company.append([company_name,street_ad,city_ad,state_ad,zip_code, phone])
      print(modeling_company) 
  except Exception as e:
       print(f'Error occurred: {e}')
```

I tried for loop to work once and append on the modelinig_company variable but it is working endlessly

Comment: You get the same list because you always print the same list. Did you mean `print(modeling_company[-1])`?

Comment: Your code works well except you display the whole list on each iteration. Probably yesterday you put the `print(modeling_company)` outside the loop

Comment: Did you really got into an infinite loop? The whole code executed in my machine in less than a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have a list of URLs to process, it's often a good idea to implement multithreading for optimum performance. For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from time import perf_counter

url = 'https://business.narimn.org/list/searchalpha/a'
modeling_company = []


def process_url(url):
    with requests.get(url) as response:
        try:
            response.raise_for_status()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
            company_name = soup.find('h1', class_='gz-pagetitle').get_text()
            address = soup.find('li', class_='list-group-item gz-card-address')
            street_ad = address.find('span', class_='gz-street-address').get_text() if address else ''
            city_ad = address.find('span', class_='gz-address-city').get_text() if address else ''
            state_ad = address.find('span', itemprop='addressRegion').get_text() if address else ''
            zip_code = address.find('span', itemprop='postalCode').get_text() if address else ''
            p_n = soup.find('li', class_='list-group-item gz-card-phone')
            phone = p_n.find('span', itemprop='telephone').get_text() if p_n else ''
            modeling_company.append([company_name, street_ad, city_ad, state_ad, zip_code, phone])
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

def get_urls(soup):
    for cl in soup.find_all('div', class_='gz-list-card-wrapper'):
        if (a_tag := cl.find('a')):
            try:
                yield a_tag['href']
            except Exception:
                pass

def main():
    with requests.get(url) as response:
        response.raise_for_status()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
        with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            executor.map(process_url, get_urls(soup))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _start = perf_counter()
    main()
    _end = perf_counter()
    print(modeling_company)
    print(f'Duration={_end-_start:.2f}s')
```

This runs in less than 3 seconds on my machine